Pyspark Merge - whenMatchedUpdate keeps on inserting records even if there are only updates
(1) In this scenario is based on reading records from bronze, merging into silver.
But even if there no new records, where it processes whenMatchedUpdate, and with
no new records it still inserts new records everytime.
#Identify incoming records that have a primary key already in silver table
#(These include the candidates for update)
newRecordsToInsert = bronze_df \
  .alias("updates") \
  .join(deltaTableSilver.toDF().alias("silver"), "TablePrimaryKey") \
  .where("silver.IsActive = true AND updates.ChangeHash <> silver.ChangeHash")

#Combine insert and update records
stagedUpdates = (
  newRecordsToInsert
  .selectExpr("NULL as mergeKey", "updates.*")
  .unionByName(bronze_df.selectExpr("TablePrimaryKey as mergeKey", "*"))
)

Creates a dynamic dictionary for inserting at whenNotMatchedInsert if
there is new data to insert
keys = stagedUpdates.columns
values = ['staged_updates.' + direction for direction in stagedUpdates.columns]
dynamic_dict = {}
for i in range(len(keys)):
    dynamic_dict[keys[i]] = values[i]
dynamic_dict.pop('mergeKey')
dynamic_dict.pop('TSInserted')

# dynamic_dict.pop('UpdatedTime')
dynamic_dict.update({"TSInserted": lit(current_datetime)})
dynamic_dict.update({"UpdateDate": lit(current_datetime)})

Apply SCD Type 2 merge operation using whenMatchedUpdate when there are not new records to insert, else a whenNotMatchedInsert to insert the new records
deltaTableSilver.alias("silver").merge(
  stagedUpdates.alias("staged_updates"),
  "silver.TablePrimaryKey = staged_updates.mergeKey") \
.whenMatchedUpdate(
  condition = "silver.IsActive = True AND silver.ChangeHash <>       
 staged_updates.ChangeHash",
  set = {                                     
    "IsActive": lit(False),
    "ValidTo": lit(previous_day_date),
    "UpdateDate":lit(current_datetime)
  }
).whenNotMatchedInsert(
  values = dynamic_dict
).execute()`

I tried to display dataframe outputs at every step or show information to determine if there are duplicates, but I don't see any duplicates.
The question I have is, why does it insert every time the process runs on the upsert (whenMatchedUpdate) area if there no entries to insert.
